# Maps navigation status bar cuts my app's window from bottom in iOS

Tags: ios, uistatusbar

I have a app which works well in normal condition.

Now, when navigation is turned on in background, the status bar height becomes 40 and my window(View) is cut by 20 pixels from bottom.

How to fix it? Here is the image:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: I dont really understand your problem, can you explain it a bit more? When does this occour?

Comment: I'm unable to attach an image

Comment: reduce the height of your view by 20 and then check

Comment: Where do I do that? applicationbecameActive ?

Comment: the blue bar in your screen shot it comes when your application is using location service when your application is in background. Can you explain exact when this occurred?

Comment: When I opened the app from recent Apps

Comment: but is that stick on the screen when your app become active?

Comment: screen shot says Google Map is using your location but actually your application is using the location , right?

Comment: No, my app doesn't use Location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77164/discussion-between-vnj-and-malav-soni).

Comment: @VaibhavJhaveri have you solved this problem? I'm currently facing with the same issue.